# Check selected item of ListView

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a ListView and need to check, which item has been clicked.
The way I have it, it only shows my the selected item when I use the scrollwheel of my mouse (when testing it in the Eclipse emulator). When I test it on a real mobile device, it doesn't react at all.

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listItems);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);

listView.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
            int arg2, long arg3) {
        myFunction(listView.getSelectedItem());
    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `setOnItemClickListener` **instead of** `setOnItemSelectedListener`

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                    long id) {
            //get value for listItems using position    

                     String str =listItems[position];                   
                     myFunction(str);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think better you need to use on onListItemClick listener

```
     public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View v, int position, long id)
              {
                parent.setItemChecked(position, parent.isItemChecked(position));
         Toast.makeText(this,  "You have selected" + items[position],30).show();
                }
```