# Cannot capture listview itemselected

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, android-listview

I'm trying to capture the item clicked on in a listview.  Everything I've seen here deals with Xamarin Forms, I am NOT using Xamarin Forms.  I build my listview and display it fine, but I cannot figure out how to capture the item click.  My build code:

```
ListView PhoneNumberList;
PhoneNumberList = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.listViewNumbers);

ListOfPhoneNumbers = new List<string>();
if (PhoneNumberData.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
{
    foreach (DataRow MyDataRow in PhoneNumberData.Tables[0].Rows)
    {
        ListOfPhoneNumbers.Add(MyDataRow["FirstName"].ToString() + " " + MyDataRow["LastName"].ToString() + " " + MyDataRow["PhoneNumber"].ToString());
    }
}
else
{
    ListOfPhoneNumbers.Add("Currently there are no phone numbers available in this list
}
ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,    Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItemMultipleChoice, ListOfPhoneNumbers);
PhoneNumberList.Adapter = adapter;
```

This code displays the name and phone number as intended, but I cannot figure out how to detect when the Listview is clicked.  I tried:

```
PhoneNumberList.ItemSelected += (sender, args) =>
{
    var Sel = PhoneNumberList.SelectedItem;
};
```

But it never gets called on the click.  I've also tried:

```
PhoneNumberList.ItemSelected += delegate (object sender, AdapterView.ItemSelectedEventArgs args) { PhoneNumberList_ItemSelected(); };
```

PhoneNumberList_ItemSelected never gets called either.

My Listview XML:

```
<ListView
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="148.4dp"
    android:id="@+id/listViewNumbers" />
```

So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=android+listview+itemselected+does+not+fire+site:stackoverflow.com

Comment: @Jason Already have done that search, tried every this that was displayed once I removed those that reference Xamarin Forms, nothing works.

Comment: @ToolMakerSteve `<ListView.ItemTemplate>` is Xamarin.Forms MVC method of creating a listview, this is not Xamarin.Forms.

Comment: OK, my mistake. Searching `android listview detect itemselected`, I see some non-Xamarin solutions that could be adapted to Xamarin.Android c#. Most notably: [use Item Click instead of Item Selected](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10817359/199364). If you get this to work, write an answer below, showing what this looks like in Xamarin.Android.

Comment: NOTE: you mention searching and finding links that DON'T work; its useful to list a couple of those in question, so people know what you've tried. Is this one of the "fixes" you already tried?

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve I've been looking a that and related stuff for a few hours now, I'm not familar with java or kotlin, so its a slog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, after slogging around the internet for a few hours, I was able to work it out.  It was rather simple and I had already discovered the answer, I just formated one statement wrong and it sent me on a wild goose chase to find the answer.  My updated code:

```
ListView PhoneNumberList;
PhoneNumberList = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.listViewNumbers);

ListOfPhoneNumbers = new List<string>();
if (PhoneNumberData.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
{
    foreach (DataRow MyDataRow in PhoneNumberData.Tables[0].Rows)
    {
        ListOfPhoneNumbers.Add(MyDataRow["FirstName"].ToString() + " " + MyDataRow["LastName"].ToString() + " " + MyDataRow["PhoneNumber"].ToString());
    }
}
else
{
    ListOfPhoneNumbers.Add("Currently there are no phone numbers available in this list
}
ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,      Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItemMultipleChoice, ListOfPhoneNumbers);
PhoneNumberList.Adapter = adapter;
```

Exactly the same, now I add the one line of code I just couldn't get right (duh):

```
PhoneNumberList.ItemClick += PhoneNumberList_ItemClick;
```

Originally I had used `PhoneNumberList.ItemClick += PhoneNumberList_ItemClick();` and the error it generated sent me off on that aforementioned wild goose chase and there went several hours of my life I'll never get back, lol.  The `PhoneNumberList_ItemClick` code:

```
void PhoneNumberList_ItemClick(object sender, AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    // We now can write code here to set the checkbox in the listview to checked
    // All I got to do now is figure out how to do THAT.  Stay tuned ....
}
```

So, hopefully this will save someone the ordeal I put myself through.

**** Update ****

Didn't take long to figure out how to set the item clicked's checkbok, changes to `PhoneNumberList_ItemClick` code below:

```
void PhoneNumberList_ItemClick(object sender, AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    ListView MyListView = (ListView)sender;
    if (MyListView.IsItemChecked(e.Position))
    {
        MyListView.SetItemChecked(e.Position, true);
    }
    else
    {
        MyListView.SetItemChecked(e.Position, false);
    }
}
```

.... And that's all folks ....